# What is the ownerType of RoutedUICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

I am trying to understand the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.routeduicommand.-ctor) parameters of [`RoutedUICommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.routeduicommand).

- What is the `ownerType` argument for?
- Is it a valid solution to just pass `null` or `typeof(object)` as `ownerType`?
- What is the value of `ownerType`, when calling the empty constructor?

My current context is following:

```
public static class CustomApplicationCommands
{
    public static RoutedUICommand SettingsCommand = new RoutedUICommand(
        text: "Opens the settings window",
        name: nameof(SettingsCommand),
        ownerType: typeof(object), // ???
        inputGestures: new InputGestureCollection(new InputGesture[] {
            new KeyGesture(Key.F10)
        })
    );
}
```

Feel free to ask for more information. I will really appreciate your answers. Thank you!

Comment: *The type that is registering the command* (mentioned in the online documentation) means the class that declares your SettingsCommand, i.e. CustomApplicationCommands.

Comment: the `ownerType` will be `null` if you call the empty constructor. You can find source code over at [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/RoutedUICommand.cs,0af85198d819d95b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the ownerType argument for?

It's used internally to [convert commands to and from strings](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandConverter.cs,c33c2cc8a770331f), e.g., when reading or writing Xaml.  It's also used in [computing the `Text` property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/RoutedUICommand.cs,42c79a702d8996d1).

> Is it a valid solution to just pass `null` or `typeof(object)` as ownerType?
>   What is the value of `ownerType`, when calling the empty constructor?

Yes, you may pass `null`, and that is indeed what happens when calling the default constructor.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds!  Fleshed out your answer a bit and added a link to the more interesting usage in `CommandConverter`.